# Best way to parse VisualStudio .csproj file using python

Tags: python, visual-studio, parsing, csproj

What is the best way to parse Visual Studio `.csproj` file using python, for further modification?

It is some `.csproj` file:

```
...
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="SomeAssembly, Version=1.1.1.1"/>      
...
</ItemGroup>
...
```

I want to insert this:

```
<HintPath>path/to/SomeAassembly.dll</HintPath>
```

into the `<Reference/>` node.

Comment: Better than finding string like "Reference" and split other part of string with regular expression. And, after that, insert HintPath tag and close Reference tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS project files are XML. Python comes with a number of XML parsing libraries: http://docs.python.org/library/markup.html

Either of `xml.parsers.expat` or `xml.minidom` could accomplish what you describe. For processing small XML documents like VS project files, choosing among them is a matter of taste. The example code in the documentation for each should help you decide.

An elegant alternative, especially if you have many such transformations to apply, would be to [use a filter object with the xml.sax API](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipsaxflex/index.html).

Comment: I used `minidom`. Unfortunately, Visual Studio has a very specific formatter used for `.csproj` files, and my Python script modified the formatting in many aspects, which created false diffs in the SCM. Any ideas how one can address this?

Comment: If minimising diffs is very important to you, then maybe an XML parser isn't the way to go, and it's better to treat this as a string transformation problem, i.e. attack it with regexp substitutions. That'll be much more brittle though.

Comment: That's what I thought I might employ next time I have a similar task. Thanks for sharing! Maybe this concern will be relevant for Eugen as well.

Comment: Would it help to make two commits to the SCM: One after simply loading and `toprettyxml`ing the file in order to normalise the formatting, and then another with the actual change?

Comment: ...And then opening every modified solution in Visual Studio and forcing Visual Studio to save it (with its normal formatting). Otherwise, next time you do a normal change (e.g. add a file) you'll get false diffs again, albeit in the other direction. Maybe regexps are not so bad, after all.

Comment: Of course, `minidom` is implemented in python, so if you're dealing with a lot of this kind of stuff, you could always copy and adapt that code, modifying the `writexml` implementations to format in Visual Studio style. Myself, I just accept the bogus diffs.

Comment: @slowdog let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2174/discussion-between-helgi-and-slowdog)